# Paypal Adaptive Payment sandbox account and unilateral receiver not allowed

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have some trouble understanding what's wrong with my sandbox accounts when I try to use Paypal Adaptive Payments. After hours of fighting, I guess it's time for me to ask for some help.

The problem is quite simple. When I use the credentials I generated in the [Sandbox Test Accounts page](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/) of my account, our system is returning an error "Account not found. Unilateral receiver not allowed in chained payment is restricted". When I'm using the test credentials provided by the company that developed the escrow module we are using, it's working. As we did this test for exactly the same request (just API credentials are changing), my guess at this point is that there is something wrong with my credentials.

My Paypal account is verified and is a business account (not sure if relevant as I'm using the sandbox right now). The sandbox account I'm using is also verified and a business account. Do I maybe have to do something for Sandbox API accounts to work with the adaptive payments?

Regards

Comment: There must be something different about the receiver emails when you're testing.  Maybe all you're changing is the credentials, but then based on those credentials there could be logic using different emails..??  Need to get a look at the raw API requests for the two different calls to verify that the email addresses do indeed exist in the PayPal sandbox system.  Based on the error at least one of the emails included does not have a PayPal account in the sandbox.

Comment: When I checked the requests, only the API credentials in the request header were changed. After more digging, it's finally working with the sandbox account details from another paypal account. The main reason I found can be that both sender and receiver sandbox accounts were generated from the same live account. As soon as I use two accounts from two different live accounts, it's working.